# Почему перестал работать Telegram бот после подключения к открытым линиям Битрикс24?

Tags: php, битрикс, telegram-bot, telegram, rest

Я создал телеграм бота по инструкции из https://core.telegram.org/ 
Вот бот https://tele.click/don_corleone_VG_bot все работало, и бот отвечал на команды.
Но после подключения к Битрикс24, бот перестает отвечать на команды.
Бот снова начинает работать если перейти по ссылке активации Webhook
https://api.telegram.org/bot********:***************v7GpB5qwVbNw0/setWebhook?url=xxxxxxxxxxxxx/bbott/bot.php.

Но тогда пропадает интеграция с битрикс и отправленные в телеграм сообщения не приходят в битрикс.

Вопрос: может ли вообще работать телеграм бот интегрированный с Битрикс24?
Если да, то сталкивался ли кто то с такой проблемой и как ее решал?

Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь.

Код Бота

```
<?php
define('BOT_TOKEN', '********:AAGDq4-UB***********GpB5qwVbNw0');
define('API_URL', 'https://api.telegram.org/bot*****:******************v7GpB5qwVbNw0/');

function apiRequestWebhook($method, $parameters) {
    if (!is_string($method)) {
        error_log("Method name must be a string\n");
        return false;
    }

    if (!$parameters) {
        $parameters = array();
    } else if (!is_array($parameters)) {
        error_log("Parameters must be an array\n");
        return false;
    }

    $parameters["method"] = $method;

    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    echo json_encode($parameters);
    return true;
}

function exec_curl_request($handle) {
    $response = curl_exec($handle);

    if ($response === false) {
        $errno = curl_errno($handle);
        $error = curl_error($handle);
        error_log("Curl returned error $errno: $error\n");
        curl_close($handle);
        return false;
    }

    $http_code = intval(curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE));
    curl_close($handle);

    if ($http_code >= 500) {
        // do not wat to DDOS server if something goes wrong
        sleep(10);
        return false;
    } else if ($http_code != 200) {
        $response = json_decode($response, true);
        error_log("Request has failed with error {$response['error_code']}: {$response['description']}\n");
        if ($http_code == 401) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid access token provided');
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        $response = json_decode($response, true);
        if (isset($response['description'])) {
            error_log("Request was successful: {$response['description']}\n");
        }
        $response = $response['result'];
    }

    return $response;
}

function apiRequest($method, $parameters) {
    if (!is_string($method)) {
        error_log("Method name must be a string\n");
        return false;
    }

    if (!$parameters) {
        $parameters = array();
    } else if (!is_array($parameters)) {
        error_log("Parameters must be an array\n");
        return false;
    }

    foreach ($parameters as $key => &$val) {
        // encoding to JSON array parameters, for example reply_markup
        if (!is_numeric($val) && !is_string($val)) {
            $val = json_encode($val);
        }
    }
    $url = API_URL.$method.'?'.http_build_query($parameters);

    $handle = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);

    return exec_curl_request($handle);
}

function apiRequestJson($method, $parameters) {
    if (!is_string($method)) {
        error_log("Method name must be a string\n");
        return false;
    }

    if (!$parameters) {
        $parameters = array();
    } else if (!is_array($parameters)) {
        error_log("Parameters must be an array\n");
        return false;
    }

    $parameters["method"] = $method;

    $handle = curl_init(API_URL);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($parameters));
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));

    return exec_curl_request($handle);
}

function processMessage($message) {
    // process incoming message
    $message_id = $message['message_id'];
    $chat_id = $message['chat']['id'];
    if (isset($message['text'])) {
        // incoming text message
        $text = $message['text'];
        if (strpos($text, "/start") === 0) {

            apiRequestJson("sendMessage", array('chat_id' => $chat_id, "text" => 'Hello', 'reply_markup' => array(
                'keyboard' => array(array('Hello', 'Hi')),
                'one_time_keyboard' => true,
                'resize_keyboard' => true)));

        } else if ($text === "Hello" || $text === "Hi") {
            apiRequest("sendMessage", array('chat_id' => $chat_id, "text" => 'Nice to meet you'));
        } else if (strpos($text, "/stop") === 0) {
            // stop now
        } else if ($text === "test" || $text === "fuck") {
            apiRequest("sendMessage", array('chat_id' => $chat_id, "text" => 'No cool'));
        } else {
            apiRequestWebhook("sendMessage", array('chat_id' => $chat_id, "reply_to_message_id" => $message_id, "text" => 'Cool'));
        }
    } else {
        apiRequest("sendMessage", array('chat_id' => $chat_id, "text" => 'I understand only text messages'));
    }
}


define('WEBHOOK_URL', 'https://test.vorobievy-gory.kharkov.ua/bbott/bot.php');

if (php_sapi_name() == 'cli') {
    // if run from console, set or delete webhook
    apiRequest('setWebhook', array('url' => isset($argv[1]) && $argv[1] == 'delete' ? '' : WEBHOOK_URL));
    exit;
}


$content = file_get_contents("php://input");
$update = json_decode($content, true);

if (!$update) {
    // receive wrong update, must not happen
    exit;
}

if (isset($update["message"])) {
    processMessage($update["message"]);
}
```

Comment: Токен-то не стоило в код вставлять, ага.

Comment: Спасибо, поправил)

Comment: Не править надо, а на новый уже менять.

Comment: Спасибо, уже поменял)

Comment: В истории изменения вопроса можно отрыть ваш код, Владислав :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что открытые линии используют переданный им токен "в своих целях", а именно регистрируют хуки на свой хост. Естественно, что бот будет работать только с активным хостом - в случае вебхуков, а в случае long-polling - только если не был зарегистрирован вебхук. Поэтому выбирайте что-то одно - либо открытые линии, либо своя логика. Либо делайте ещё одного бота.